# Is there a Visual studio plugin for visualizing red-green time for a TDD session?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, tdd, visualization

I read a post by Joshua Kerievsky about 'Limited Red Time' [Link](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/The-Limited-Red-Society)

His org. Industrial Logic as part of a training module, has a screen where you upload an archive. In return, the screen shows you a graph of how much time were you in the red state vs the green state. It also hooks up with Resharper and annotates points at which the specific refactorings were performed.

The resulting graph gives some vital insights to self-assess your skills/behavior. e.g. I am myself guilty of getting into a red state and not giving in to a revert+retry, instead hacking away at it for a few hours before I get it to green (if I am lucky).

From my limited exposure, it looks to be proprietary. Is there such a visualization plugin for Visual Studio that is available ?

Comment: Seems like that they're coming up with another 'Album' called Sessions, which contains this visualization tool. I think you'd need to purchase this album so that you can upload your session data to their web server, where they analyze it and send the report back to you. Still under development for .Net, so nothing is certain.

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking at [Beacons](http://code.google.com/p/gishu-util/wiki/Beacons), a VS 2010 extension which shows you detailed information about your testing session. A demo of it can be found [here](http://vimeo.com/27977192).

Must admit that I´ve not used this myself, as I only found out about it the other day whilst on holiday. But it looks promising enough, and it's free.

Comment: I'm still working on that one :) A couple more videos and some more code later, I'll have a usable release and the related infrastructure (docs/feedback forum/wiki) etc. Send me a email (id in my profile) and I'll ping you as soon as I have it up.

Comment: Hi Gishu. I didn´t realise you are the author of Beacons. Your extension looks very interesting. I like the idea of quick feedback after running unit tests. I would be interested in trying it out when I get home from holiday. I will send you an email when I arrive home later this week. I have tried NCrunch and Mighty Moose, which are both very clever tools, but they don´t quite work for me yet.

Comment: Hi Jason, uploaded a couple of more videos http://goo.gl/7P5kK (that double as 'getting started' videos for the extension. If you could send me your post-session screenshots via email along with your review of the session, that'd be great. I'm trying to extract some repeatable good/bad patterns - so far I'm the only test subject.:)

Answer (score 0):

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/B5EC8514-E251-41D2-8728-C1D0F5FD067D is an extension that builds timesheets based on your TFS activities... possibly you could set it up to support this? Of course if you're not using TFS then I doubt it would work.